# Why do I get this part when I try to publish my portfolio?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm trying to publish my portfolio, deployment goes through but I get this screen when I try to access my page. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?[image]

When i open the link i got this on my screen instead of my portfolio.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If GitHub can't see a index.html file to serve, it will instead server your README.md file as a backup.

Either ensure an index.html file exists in the route of your repository, or select the folder (maybe `public` or `src`) that contains the index.htnl file in your repository using the dropdown in the screenshot you attached.

Also, just so you are aware, the repository name has to match your GitHub username in order to get the domain with no sub-directory. From your screenshot, it looks like your GitHub username is `m1rzoni`, but you have created a repository called `mirza.github.io`. As `mirza` is seemingly not your GitHub username, you cannot use `mirza.github.io` as that is reserved for whoever has the `mirza` account. This leaves you with three options:

- Rename your repository to `m1rzoni.github.io` and have `https://m1rzoni.github.io` as your URL
- Rename your repository to something else and have `https://m1rzoni.github.io/<reponame>` as your URL
- Change your username to `mirza` if it is free, or something else, and set the repository name to match, to then have `https://<username>.github.io` as the URL.

Hope that's clear :)

Comment: @MirzaŠabanović Just updated the answer with some notes about the URL, which may or may not be useful. If this answer solves your problem, please make sure to set it as Solved to close it out.

Comment: Thank you a lot i changed it to a M1rzoni and it's working fine.. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MirzaŠabanović No worries, glad you sorted it. If you can set my answer as the solution to close out the question as answered, that would be great!